# Ajax success part is not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter framework with ajax and jquery

This my ajax code

```
$('#email').blur(function(){
    var email=$("#email").val();    

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/paymybill/ajax/email_check",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: email,
        success: function(data) {
           alert('working ......');
           alert(data);
        }

    });
});
```

This my controller code

```
public function email_check(){

    echo "xxxxx";
    return;
}
```

problem is that it don't alert message in "success:" part of ajax code please help me
 ( if i will do any error in the controller both the messages are displaying but second message  with the error message ) please help me i m new to ajax

Comment: Can you see something happening in your developer console like Chrome Inspector / Firebug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#email').blur(function(){
      var email=$("#email").val();  

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/paymybill/ajax/email_check",
            global: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                    'email':email, // you should give a key to the variable
                  },
            success: function(data) {
               alert('working ......'); 
               alert(data); // gives xxxxx
            }

    });

public function email_check(){

         $email = $_POST['email']; //gives the entered email id
         echo "xxxxx"; // no need to return anything.just echoing is fine
}
```

Comment: how to access email value in email_check function that send in ajax please help me

Comment: @Anudeep Check the function.. I've added a line to it

Comment: hi dude it access data emailid only after i clicked submitte button otherwise it not passing value any suggention plz

Comment: @Anudeep If blur is working,then you should be able to send ajax data. Debug it by adding alert after every step in your jquery

Comment: i tried alert in success part in ajax it is alrting message the only problem is i can't able value in codeigniter controller.. when i tried to  echo ">>>>>>>>>>".$this->input->post('email'); only  ">>>>>>>>" part is displaying (when i press submite button and i tried blur function then it works with sumitted value )

Comment: @Anudeep You've given `var email=$("#email").val();` in jquery,right.. Now check whether you got the value or not. Add `alert(email)` after it

Comment: @Anudeep It happens ;) Happy coding.

Comment: please check dis question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062277/how-to-get-each-value-from-json-method

Answer (score 1):

```
data: email,
```

Should be in a  key value format..

```
data: { 'email' : email},
```

Also specify the return type.. Maybe 'json' , 'html'

```
dataType:'json'
```

Also add the error function to check what the error might be..

Comment: POST http://localhost/paymybill/ajax/email_check 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4
send jquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) sign_up:454
f.event.handle jquery.min.js:3
i.handle.k   (SHOWING ERROR SOMETHING LIKE WHEN ADD CODE IN ERROR FUNCTION error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
} )