# How to get each value from json method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

ajax

```
$('#stb_no').blur(function(){
    var stb_no= $('#stb_no').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/paymybill/ajax/stb_info",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'stb_no':stb_no, // you should give a key to the variable
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#amount').val(data);
     //     $(".email_msg").addClass("red");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller code

```
public function stb_info(){
    $stb_no=$this->mso->alldata_stbno($this->input->post('stb_no'));
    echo json_encode($stb_no);
}
```

i am getting out put

```
[{"sxb_no":"xxxxxx","mzo_name":"xx","cto_name":"xxxxx","area":"xxxxx","name_sxb_owr":"","mobile_no":"xxxxxx","email":"xxxxx@yahoo.com","amount":"xxx"}]
```

i need to know how to get each values ex:- if i want get email id what i should i do in jquery please help me i new to ajax

Comment: Depends on the number of rows returned, but basically : myArray[0]['email']

Comment: myArray stands for array name???? but i don't have name i think i m displaying this in text box use this  $('#amount').val(data); in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers support JSON.parse(), which is defined in ECMA-262 and is the recommended way. Its usage is simple (I will use your example JSON):

`var json = '{"area":"xxxxx",...,"email":"xxxxx@yahoo.com","amount":"xxx"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);`

Note that obj.email can't be used, because you are parsing an array.

Edit: Checking your comments you need to know that the data parameter is the JSON object, parse it first and then you can do:

`$('#amount').val(obj[0].email);`

Answer (score 1):

Just add to `$.ajax` call parameter `dataType:"json"` and Jquery will parse it in success parameter automatically. Then use it `data[0]['email'];`

Comment: check my code type:post i m using ... any problem with that using 2 type?

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
$('#stb_no').blur(function(){
    var stb_no= $('#stb_no').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/paymybill/ajax/stb_info",
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            'stb_no':stb_no, // you should give a key to the variable
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#email').val(data[0]['email']);

            //OR
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#email').val(obj[0].email);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if you has parsed the data don't need to use the array notations, use the object notation instead